# Is it possible to index "SELECT domain_name from domains WHERE 'x.example.com' like domain_name" where domain_name contains "%.example.com"

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Hey, I am trying to create a system to match wildcard domain names. Although the query above will work for me is it possible to index it at all?

I don't have access to the DB to do any clever stuff as I am using Heroku to host my app but I can add indexes easy enough?

Thanks!

Edit:

I would like to match wildcard domain names in my database. So I have a table with a column called domain_name and this can contain something like '%.example.com' to match if I pass in x.example.com or hello.example.com as an input parameter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between performance of the two sql queries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486472/difference-between-performance-of-the-two-sql-queries)

Comment: @Kirk Woll: That's for MySQL, not PostgreSQL

Comment: I'm also not sure it's the same because the side that items appear on the like may be relevant.

Comment: Please post the CREATE TABLE statement, and an example of what you are actually using in the question.

Comment: I have updated the information. I have actually solved this outside the database but I think the question still stands of can you index with the percentage at the front of the string stored in a column of the database. I don't have the create statement to hand as the ORM does this but I'm not sure it will help much anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use reverse function and function index.
http://www.postgres.cz/index.php/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks

If You use Postgresql 9.1 "reverse" function is build in.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reverse(varchar) RETURNS varchar AS $$ 
  $reversed = reverse $_[0]; 
  return $reversed; 
$$ LANGUAGE plperlu IMMUTABLE;

CREATE INDEX rev_email ON users( (reverse(email) ) varchar_pattern_ops );
SELECT * FROM _users WHERE reverse(email) LIKE reverse ('%.cz');
```

Comment: Does this work when it is in fact the column on the right hand side I guess it does? Seems like a nice solution. I'll accept it if nothing else appears that definitely works with the column itself containing the %.